# Problem With @Media rules. Trying to Display Well in Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a site to display well in mobile as well as desktop but there is one part of the site that doesn't render well it's good in desktop but when I switch to mobile:

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezD1I.png)

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu58W.png)

I've been playing around with different media queries to no avail. Adjusting the scale does nothing Here is the code. Thanks in advance to any who help.

```
const date = new Date();
var minutesNow= date.getMinutes();
var remainder = minutesNow%15;
var minutesLeft  = 15-remainder;
var secondsNow = date.getSeconds();


let time = (86400 -(3600*24 - 60*minutesLeft + secondsNow)); 
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(time, {
    countdown: true
});
```

```
#clock1 {
    display: inline-block;
width: auto;
  
}
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #clock1 {
  transform: scale(0.8)
  }
}
```

```
<br>
<link href="https://api.chipware.co.za/css/flipclock.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.chipware.co.za/js/flipclock-min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="clock" id="clock1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing Desktop first approach:
Use 'flex' box instead of 'inline-block' on the parent

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
  justify-content: middle;
  aligh-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

And for using media query just, change the direction to vertical:

```
.container{
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

If on mobile you want one part of the clock per line, just adjust the margin of the child element on smaller screens to make each part use width of the screen.

Also, try and use, width on each child element and 'flex-grow' property to get a better understanding.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp